# Conversion uint8 to int16

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, astropy, fits

I'm trying to convert a uint8 image to int16 to be saved in fit format.
The img5 display correctly but after the conversion to int16, the image is just gray.

```
img5 = img1Reg.copy()
cv2.imshow("img5", img5)

integer_array = img5.astype(np.int16)

cv2.imshow("integer_array", integer_array)

hdr_primary = fits.Header()
n = np.zeros((801, 1201), dtype=np.int16)
primary_hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(integer_array, header=hdr_primary)
hdu_list = fits.HDUList([primary_hdu])
hdu_list.writeto('my_file.fit', overwrite=True)
```

I try several things but the most successful was using the normalized function but the image don't show any contrast, looks flat and the background is not black anymore (astro image).

```
img_normalized = cv2.normalize(img5, None, 0, 32000, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
integer_array = img_normalized.astype(np.int16)
```

Is there anyway I could get sharp/black background as per img5 after converting to int16?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can't see your images.

Comment: are you sure it's *int16 (signed)*? are you sure it's not *uint16 (unsigned)*? why did you not scale the values to stretch the 16-bit range?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
integer_array = (img5.astype(np.float32)/255.0*65535.0-32768.0).astype(np.int16)
```

That will scale properly your 0,255 range (uint8) to the -32768,32767 (int16) range.